# Como trocar uma imagem por outra dependendo da hora?

Tags: php

Estou puxando o `rss` do `instagram` de um perfil de um mercado, mas quero que as 10:00 da manhã até às `00:00` (*meia-noite*) ele exiba a foto da primeira postagem, e que a partir das `00:01` até às `9:59` da manhã ele exiba uma imagem qualquer de ilustração.

Estou tentando usar o horário sem ser do servidor para não dar erro.
O que tentei até agora funcionou apenas a exibição durante o dia, mas quando chega meia noite ele exibe a mensagem de erro.
Esse é o código:

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/comprebemsupermercado/?__a=1";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$arrData = json_decode($data, true);
$instagram_photos = $arrData['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges'][0]['node']['display_url'];

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1800'; url='index.php'>"; //atualiza a cada 30 minutos
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css?version=330'>";
echo "<div class='fundo'>";
echo "</div>";

// DEFINE O FUSO HORARIO COMO O HORARIO DE BRASILIA
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
// CRIA UMA VARIAVEL E ARMAZENA A HORA ATUAL DO FUSO-HORÀRIO DEFINIDO (BRASÍLIA)
    $hr = date(' H:i ', time());

if($hr >= 24 && $hr < 10) {
$resp = "<img class='logo' src='logo.jpg' alt=''/>";}
else if ($hr >= 10 && $hr < 24 ){
$resp = "<img class='img-responsive' src='{$instagram_photos}'/>";}
else {
$resp = "Erro";}
echo "$resp";
?>
```

E esse é o CSS:

```
.img-responsive{
    position: absolute;top: 0;
    left: 200px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 900px;
    height: 900px;
}
.fundo{
    position: absolute;top: 0;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
}
.logo{
    position: absolute;top: 0;
    left: 200px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 900px;
    height: 900px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Estou puxando o `rss` do instagram de um perfil de um mercado, mas quero que as `10:00` da manhã até às `00:00` (meia-noite) ele exiba a foto da primeira postagem, e que a partir das `00:01` até às `9:59` da manhã ele exiba uma imagem qualquer de ilustração.

Faltou a parte de conhecimento de tempo onde a hora começas as `00:00` e termina no `23:59` (*não tem 24:00*), então:

```
<?php

    //G Formato 24-horas de uma hora sem zero à esquerda (0 até 23)
    $hour = (int)date('G');
    if ($hour >= 0 && $hour < 10)
    {
        // 00:00 até 09:59
    }
    else 
    {
        // 10:00 até 23:59
    }
```

<sup>Referencia: [function date](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php)</sup>

Comment: Um dica caro Virgilio, o cast `(int)` é dispensavel neste tipo de comparação, o proprio php o faz, creio que seria apenas interessante se o objetivo fosse alcançar a micro-otimização, como um loop que irá processar umas 40.000 comparações assim em "ifs".  ;)

Comment: uma dica se eu quiser uma comparação com o tipo texto neh @GuilhermeNascimento e se eu quiser força que o tipo seja um número, porque retorna um tipo texto ...

Comment: Mas o cast ou a comparação com operadores de menor e maior será o mesmo efeito para comparar numeros, compreende? Estou falando do caso especifico e não de "todos" tipos de comparação ;)

Comment: Mas eu quero assim @GuilhermeNascimento ... quero que ele faça o `cast`. Vem um e fala em comparação frouxa, vem outra e contexta, aqui nunca ninguém se satisfaz em sabedoria.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Deu erro nos dois pontos entre os números do horario

Comment: Depende o que você fez @jose113 ??? como você fez e o que deu de errado!

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
// CRIA UMA VARIAVEL E ARMAZENA A HORA ATUAL DO FUSO-HORÀRIO DEFINIDO (BRASÍLIA)
    $hour = (int)date('G');
    if ($hour >= 0 && $hour < 09:59){
$resp = "<img class='logo' src='logo.jpg' alt=''/>";}
else if ($hour >= 10:00 && $hour < 0:00 ){
$resp = "<img class='img-responsive' src='{$instagram_photos}'/>";}
else {
$resp = "Erro";}
echo "$resp";
?>

Comment: olha como você escreveu `$hour >= 0 && $hour < 09:59` é só colocar `<10` se não seguiu a minha resposta @jose113 o if ta pronto é só colocar as duas imagens dentro do cochetes

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Sim, agora mesmo seguindo sua resposta não funcionou

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98946/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-jose113).